# How to differentiate between meeting cancel and meeting create in Outloo on-send Add-in

Tags: javascript, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm trying to build an Outlook add-in that hits an external APIs each time a meeting is booked from Outlook. The external API is of two types i) create meeting ii) cancel meeting.

I'm able to capture all the data I need in my Outlook on-send add-in, except for weather the on-send is meeting save or meeting cancel. Can someone tell me which field in the `Office.context.mailbox.item` contains the info hinting if the current send is a cancel or not? (PFA screenshot of mailbox fields). Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Platform: Office 365 Windows application.

[All available properties in Office.context.mailbox.item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Gdun.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not possible via functions provided in compose mode in Office.context.mailbox.item.

We are aware for the need of this functionality, but please also open a uservoice request for this, to help prioritize new features.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins